# How to add React routing to mapped list items?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm studying React and trying to make a Todo app. I made a first section and a menu which should switch the app between two sections. I'm mapping buttons in order to add them class because they should have different styling after they are clicked. Now I need to add routing to these buttons but I can't make it work.

This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Todo from "../Todo/Todo";
import About from "../About/About";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import classnames from "classnames";
import styles from "./App.module.css";

const App = () => {
  const [clicked, setClicked] = useState("");  
  const buttons = ["About me", 'Todos'];

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav className={styles.menu}>
          <ul className={styles.nav}>
            {buttons.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <li
                  key={index}
                  onClick={() => {
                    if (clicked === index) {
                      setClicked();
                    } else {
                      setClicked(index);
                    }
                  }}
                >
                  <Link to={`/buttons/${index}`}>
                    {
                      <button
                        className={classnames({ [styles.button]: true,       [styles.selected]: clicked === index
                        })}
                      >
                        {item}
                      </button>
                    }
                  </Link>
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </nav>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/todo" element={<Todo />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );`

export default App;
```

The error message I get in console is 'No routes matched location "/buttons/0"'. And the same for "/buttons/1".
Probably I indicated paths wrong somehow but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You do not have any route with a path that matches `/buttons/...`
There are 2 routes, one for `/` only, and one for `/todo`

Comment: I see, thank you, I thought that's what Link tag was for. I changed Routes code to 
<Routes>
    <Route path="buttons" element={<App buttons={buttons} />} />
        <Route path=":button/0" element={<Todo />} />
        <Route path=":button/1" element={<About />} />
    <Route />
</Routes>
and now it's working.